# django admin load error: ImportError at /admin/login/ No module named backends

Tags: django, python-2.7

All of a sudden, I don't seem to be able to access the admin on my django app. Here's the error message I'm getting, any idea what could have happened? I don't think I changed any admin or settings data since I last opened it.

> ImportError at /admin/login/
>   No module named backends
>   Request Method: POST
>   Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/admin/login/?next=/admin/
>   Django Version: 1.9.dev20150119161257
>   Exception Type: ImportError
>   Exception Value:
>   No module named backends
>   Exception Location: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/**init**.py in import_module, line 37
>   Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
>   Python Version: 2.7.6
>   Python Path:
>   ['/Users/saraabi/Sites/django_testapp',
>    '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-6.0.6-py2.7.egg',
>    '/Users/saraabi/django-trunk',
>    '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip',
>    '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7',
>    '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
>    '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
>    '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
>    '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python',
>    '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
>    '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
>    '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
>    '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC',
>    '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages']
>   Server time:    Thu, 16 Jul 2015 23:31:24 +0000
>
> Environment:
>
> Request Method: POST Request URL:
>   http://localhost:8000/admin/login/?next=/admin/
>
> Django Version: 1.9.dev20150119161257 Python Version: 2.7.6 Installed
>   Applications: ('django.contrib.admin',  'django.contrib.auth', 
>   'django.contrib.contenttypes',  'django.contrib.sessions', 
>   'django.contrib.messages',  'django.contrib.staticfiles', 
>   'testapp') Installed Middleware:
>   ('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware')
>
> Traceback: File
>   "/Users/saraabi/django-trunk/django/core/handlers/base.py" in
>   get_response
>     131.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) File "/Users/saraabi/django-trunk/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in
>   _wrapped_view_func
>     54.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs) File "/Users/saraabi/django-trunk/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in login
>     388.         return login(request, **defaults) File "/Users/saraabi/django-trunk/django/views/decorators/debug.py" in
>   sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper
>     76.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs) File "/Users/saraabi/django-trunk/django/utils/decorators.py" in
>   _wrapped_view
>     110.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs) File "/Users/saraabi/django-trunk/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in
>   _wrapped_view_func
>     54.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs) File "/Users/saraabi/django-trunk/django/contrib/auth/views.py" in login
>     40.         if form.is_valid(): File "/Users/saraabi/django-trunk/django/forms/forms.py" in is_valid
>     136.         return self.is_bound and not self.errors File "/Users/saraabi/django-trunk/django/forms/forms.py" in errors
>     128.             self.full_clean() File "/Users/saraabi/django-trunk/django/forms/forms.py" in full_clean
>     345.         self._clean_form() File "/Users/saraabi/django-trunk/django/forms/forms.py" in _clean_form
>     369.             cleaned_data = self.clean() File "/Users/saraabi/django-trunk/django/contrib/auth/forms.py" in clean
>     165.                                            password=password) File "/Users/saraabi/django-trunk/django/contrib/auth/**init**.py" in
>   authenticate
>     60.     for backend, backend_path in _get_backends(return_tuples=True): File "/Users/saraabi/django-trunk/django/contrib/auth/**init**.py" in
>   _get_backends
>     27.         backend = load_backend(backend_path) File "/Users/saraabi/django-trunk/django/contrib/auth/**init**.py" in
>   load_backend
>     21.     return import_string(path)() File "/Users/saraabi/django-trunk/django/utils/module_loading.py" in
>   import_string
>     22.     module = import_module(module_path) File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/**init**.py"
>   in import_module
>     37.     **import**(name)
>
> Exception Type: ImportError at /admin/login/ Exception Value: No
>   module named backends

Comment: Can you please post your settings.py file ?

Comment: Sure, just posted it below; thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'testapp',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'django_testapp.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'django_testapp.wsgi.application'


DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'testapp.backends.EmailBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Answer (score 0):

settings.py

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__) + '/../')

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
)

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)
SITE_ID = 1

ROOT_URLCONF = 'apps.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'apps.wsgi.application'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    PROJECT_DIR + '/templates/',
)

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```